# make call using bluetooth from android

Tags: android, bluetooth

i have a android phone without sim. i have another phone with sim in hands free profile enabled using bluetooth. is it possible to send a call number command from my android phone to that phone ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

No.
The long reason is - Handsfree profile has 2 sides / roles , one is Audio gateway and the other is Hands Free side, Android only supports the Audio gateway side and thus 2 android phones will not connect to each other via the Hands Free profile.